# Setting Marker Icon to UIImage and Properly Resizing it with a background to Make it appear as an icon

Tags: swift, google-maps, firebase, uiimage, firebase-realtime-database

the code I currently have gets a profile picture from firebase and displays it on the map as the marker icon.

```
                self.ref.child("users").child(location.key as! String).child("userPhoto").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
                    if(snapshot.exists()) {

                        let profileUrl = snapshot.value as? String
                        let url = NSURL(string: profileUrl!)
                        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                            if error != nil {
                                print(error)
                                return
                            }

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                                    marker.icon = downloadedImage

                                }


                            })

                        }).resume()
                    }
                })
```

Unfortunately, this code just plops a really big image on the map which i dont want. i want a circular image with a border/background that makes it look like a pin/marker. Like this:

[Ideal Deign of The Marker Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owJBs.png)

Would anyone know how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

P.S: I am new to swift and would really appreciate if you could show me some code with whatever solution you provide. Thanks!

Comment: please keep your answers in Swift! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func changeImageDimensions(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat, newHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
 let widthRat  = newWidth/image!.size.width
 let heightRat = newHeight/image!.size.height
 var newSize: CGSize = CGSize() 
        if(widthRat > heightRat) {
          newSize = CGSizeMake(image!.size.width * heightRat, image!.size.height * heightRat)
         } else {
           newSize = CGSizeMake(image!.size.width * widthRat,  image!.size.height * widthRat)
     }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight))
    let frameRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)
    image.drawInRect(frameRect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}

self.ref.child("users").child(location.key as! String).child("userPhoto").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
                if(snapshot.exists()) {

                    let profileUrl = snapshot.value as? String
                    let url = NSURL(string: profileUrl!)
                    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                        if error != nil {
                            print(error)
                            return
                        }

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                                marker.icon = changeImageDimensions (downloadedImage!,newWidth:CGFloat(150),newHeight:CGFloat(150))

                            }


                        })

                    }).resume()
                }
            })
```